# Generate time serie in iso-8601 format using date command, how to deal with server system date origin offset?

Tags: linux, bash, date, epoch, systemtime

I have the following bash function that generate an epoch list in iso-8601 format on a machine that runs ubuntu and it works fine. (where isdate and isint bash functions to test the input)

```
gen_epoch()
{
 #@ USAGE: gen_epoch [start_date_iso] [end_date_iso] [increment_in_seconds]
 #@
 #@ TASK : generate an epoch list (epoch list in isodate format).
 #@        result on STDOUT:               [epoch_list]
 #@        error_code      :  2             0

 ## test argument
 if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then echo "$FUNCNAME: input error [nb_of_input]"; return 2
 elif [ $( isdate $1 &> /dev/null; echo $? ) -eq 2 ]; then echo "$FUNCNAME: argument error [$1]"; return 2
 elif [ $( isdate $2 &> /dev/null; echo $? ) -eq 2 ]; then echo "$FUNCNAME: argument error [$2]"; return 2
 elif [ $( isint $3 &> /dev/null; echo $? ) -eq 2 ]; then echo "$FUNCNAME: argument error [$3]"; return 2
 else local beg=$( TZ=UTC date --date="$1" +%s ); local end=$( TZ=UTC date --date="$2" +%s ); local inc=$3; fi

 ## generate epoch
 while [ $beg -le $end ]
 do
  local date_out=$( TZ=UTC date --date="UTC 1970-01-01 $beg secs" --iso-8601=seconds ); beg=$(( $beg + $inc ))
  echo ${date_out%+*}
 done
}
```

It generates the expected values for this command line example:
`gen_epoch 2014-04-01T00:00:00 2014-04-01T07:00:00 3600`

expected values:

```
2014-04-01T00:00:00
2014-04-01T01:00:00
2014-04-01T02:00:00
2014-04-01T03:00:00
2014-04-01T04:00:00
2014-04-01T05:00:00
2014-04-01T06:00:00
2014-04-01T07:00:00
```

However i have tried this function on a server where i have no root privileges and i have found the following results:

```
2014-03-31T17:00:00
2014-03-31T18:00:00
2014-03-31T19:00:00
2014-03-31T20:00:00
2014-03-31T21:00:00
2014-03-31T22:00:00
2014-03-31T23:00:00
2014-04-01T00:00:00
```

and i have seen that the server time origin is not at 1970-01-01T00:00:00.
typing `TZ=UTC date --date="1970-01-01T00:00:00" +%s` command gives the value of `-25200` which corresponds to a 7 hours lag while it should give 0.
My question is how this problem could be corrected on the server?
Could You help me to find an equivalent solution for this function assuming that i don't know on which machine i am running it, so i have know apriori knowledge if the system time is correct or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer but too long for a comment.

I guess that this particular server is incorrectly configured upon setup. The problem is that BIOS clocks are set to localtime time, while the systems thinks it's in UTC (or vise versa) (use `hwclock` to query hardware clocks settings).

If the system is configured incorrectly and you can't fix it for any reason (don't have superuser account or whatever), I'd suggest to provide a "fixing timezone description file with your software and specify it in TZ variable like this: `TZ=:/path/to/fixing/timezone date --date="1970-01-01T00:00:00" +%s`. Obviously you have to pre-calculate which TZ description file fixes the problem and use a proper one. Usually available timezones are stored in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`

Comment: I have tried the following (may i have missunderstood your suggestion): `for i in /usr/share/zoneinfo/*; do if [ -f $i ]; then echo ${i##*/} $( TZ=$i date --date="1970-01-01T00:00:00" +%s); fi; done`. On my computer i have received obviously different results for the different time zones (for `UTC 0`, for `CET -3600`, etc..) meanwhile on the server for all of the files i have got the same value, `-25200`. Does it means those files are corrupted? On the server `hwclock` does not exist.

Comment: What is the server OS? Issue `uname -a`. The idea is to distribute a zoneinfo file suitable for a particular system and to specify it in `TZ` using `:/path/to/filename` system. The problem is that `:/filename` is a Linux (or, rather, GNU libc) extension, so you should ensure that your server is actually GNU Linux :)

Comment: I have verified, both of the machine is GNU/Linux. My machine: `Linux hostname 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and the server: `Linux hostname 2.6.18-348.3.1.el5 #1 SMP Mon Mar 11 15:43:13 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Comment: Have you got `root` access to the server? If you have, then check `/sbin/hwclock` and fix hardware clocks. If you don't, simply try to compensate incorrect system settings by choosing a timezone from the eastern hemisphere. I guess you need something like `TZ=UTC+07:00 -date="1970-01-01T00:00:00" +%s`.

Comment: Unfortunately i have not, but i can speak with the administrator :). I have tried your suggestion but i got the same `-25200` value.

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance of your answer. This question is not yet solved on our server (no root access) however your answer headed us into the good direction.